# Is it possible to prevent getServerSideProps causing a full page reload after initial load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a server-rendered next.js app which is a 3-page checkout flow. On the first page, I'm fetching various setup data such as label translations and basket items inside `getServerSideProps`, as below:

#### UserDetails.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { LabelsContext } from "../contexts";
import { Component1, Component2 } from '../components'

const UserDetails = () => {
  const labels = useContext(LabelsContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <Component1 labels={labels} />
      <Component2 labels={labels} />
    </div>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const {
    locale,
    basketId,
  } = context.res.locals;

  const { cookie } = context.req.headers;

  const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(
    GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Language': locale,
        'X-Basket': basketId,
        cookie,
      },
    },
  );

  const { labels } = await graphQLClient.request(getLabels);

  return {
    labels,
    locale,
  };
};

export default UserDetails;
```

This data is then passed from `pageProps` to local state in `_app.js`, and on to context providers from there:

#### _app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useApollo } from '@apollo/client';

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const [labels, setLabels] = useState(pageProps.labels);

  const apolloClient = useApollo(pageProps.initialApolloState);

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
      <LabelsContext.Provider value={labels}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </LabelsContext.Provider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};
```

This is working well on the initial render, as the fetches are successful and the data being set in `_app.js` state means that they're available to subsequent pages in the flow. But my issue is that when a user clicks the browser back button from page 2 back to the UserDetails page, it performs a full page reload again re-fetches the data. Re-fetching the data isn't a big issue, but when the page reloads, all of the data that was entered in the form is lost. Also, the UX is a bit jarring when all other page transitions are snappy client-side loads.

Is there a way to prevent a full page reload in this scenario once the page has already loaded once?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: It's unclear from your code alone why going back from the second page to the `UserDetails` page would trigger a full page reload. This would need further debugging, as that's not the expected behaviour. When you actually press the back button, do you see any requests failing in the dev tools `Network` tab? Namely the request to fetch the `JSON` data for `UserDetails`?

Comment: @juliomalves Yes, I do actually see UserDetails.json failing. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: What does the request URL look like? And, are you using `assetPrefix` in your `next.config.js` by any chance?

Comment: @juliomalves The request URL is ```http://localhost:3000/_next/data/development/co/details.json``` and I have ```assetPrefix: '/co/',``` in ```next.config.js```

Comment: You should probably look into moving to [`basePath` instead](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath) then, as suggested in this [issue discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/11992).

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! I looked for ages but didn't see that question! Thanks for your help @juliomalves

Comment: @juliomalves I made this change but now all of my files are returning a 404, e.g. http://localhost:3000/co/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1615892503981.

Do you know why this might be? The same URL for the files works fine when I have the assetPrefix specified instead of basePath

Comment: Try deleting your `.next` folder, then build and run again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full page reload happens because the request to retrieve the JSON data for `UserDetails` page fails during a client-side transition.

Having the [`assetPrefix`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/cdn-support-with-asset-prefix) entry in your `next.config.js`, will have the following effect:

> Next.js will automatically use your asset prefix for the JavaScript and CSS files it loads from the `/_next/` path.

However, the asset prefix does **not** affect `/_next/data/` requests from `getServerSideProps` when retrieving JSON data on the client, meaning these requests will 404, which in turn trigger the full page reload (as you are experiencing).

The solution is to use [`basePath`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath) instead of `assetPrefix`. This allows you to set a path prefix for the whole application, which includes the requests made by `getServerSideProps` to retrieve JSON data for the page.

---

Currently, there's no alternative to using `basePath` as it's the only way to add a prefix to the `/_next/data/` requests. However, there's an open discussion about the issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/25681.